# Web service : get two major version with one database

Tags: rest, service, backend

I need to upgrade my rest API : http://myserver/myapi/v1 to http://myserver/myapi/v2.
As I have several mobile applications that use version 1, I have to keep both APIs online for a while.
I use a database behind this API.

My question is simple: the database schema for v2 must evolve.

Is it necessary to create a second database for the V2 version (with the problems of synchronization between the base v1-v2)?

If I keep a single base for both versions, what are the best practices for managing both backends? (evolution of tables used in the V1 with a different scheme).
I can not find any information on this topic, we only talk about the API remained, not on how to manage the backend !!

Comment: Why not tweak the older version to get its result from the new schema? It would be similar resources so it should be possible to get most of the values (especially if the new version adds and doesn't remove resources/fields).  It might be some extra work and you don't want to work on the API that will get deprecated  but usually less than maintaining two databases etc.

Comment: 268/5000
I have to keep the old version as is the time to migrate the mobile applications from the old to the new version.
I'm amazed to find no literature on how to handle the API backend when a new major release comes up!